# Getting an error while trying to connect to database using jpa

Tags: java, jpa

Please can you help me solve this error.I am running this code in eclipse and using jpa 2.0 and below is my persistence.xml and error. any help is appreciated. I'm stuck for like a day on this.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/proxy/EntityNotFoundDelegate
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:54)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:79)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
    at com.test.Main.main(Main.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.proxy.EntityNotFoundDelegate
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 4 more
```

My Persistence.xml

```
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence

http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"

  version="2.1">

  <persistence-unit name="jpa-example" >
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>com.test.User</class>
    <properties>
      <!-- Configuring JDBC properties -->
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306//test_pk" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />

         </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: are you using maven?

Comment: Can you provide details of the classpath when your code is being executed?

Comment: Hi all thanks was able to resolve this error .I will post my solution soon

Comment: Whats the solution @user3542760?